# python: progress bar not accepting int

Tags: python

I'm trying to feed my progress bar int values from each loop but I keep getting an error which says that I'm not inputting int values:

```
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

What I'm doing is:

1. Getting the total length of the array
2. Dividing length of progress bar with array length (to get value/percentage for each item in the array)
3. Each loop the value got from step two is cast into (int) and added to total value var
4. Casting (int) on the total value var and assigning it to my progress bar

Bits and pieces of the code currently look like this:

```
(in main loop)
....
self.progress = Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100,  mode='determinate')
global that
that = self
def progress_bar(self, progress):
    progress["value"]=int(progress)
....
(in another worker thread)
....
item_count = 0
item_percent = 100 / len(my_arr)
for x in my_arr:
    item_count += 1
    pb_percent = item_count * item_percent
    pb_formatted = int(pb_formatted)
    Application.progress_bar(that, int(pb_formatted))
```

Everything seems to be right to me, yet I keep getting this error. When I print the `pb_formatted` var I can see that it is what I need for the progress bar, and I also ran some `if-else` code blocks to check if what I'm trying to input is indeed `int`.

What might be the issue?

Comment: which line is throwing error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
def progress_bar(self, progress):
    progress["value"]=int(progress)
```

`progress` here is the argument you've passed in, say 42. `42["value"] = int(42)` doesn't mean anything. How would you assign 42 to the value'th item of 42? In other words, you can't assign to `progress["value"]` because `progress` isn't a container.

You probably want `self.progress` on the left side of that `=` sign. `self.progress` is your `Progressbar` instance.

Comment: Thanks, after reading this I just realized that I wasn't calling the `self.progress` object in the function which I set the progress bar to, I got it working now.